# What is the event when and edittext is updated?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have and android layout with two edittexts one for Qty and one for rate and a textview for total amount. Now what I want to do is change/update the total amount whenever the user changes the rate or quantity fields.

What is the edittext event I am looking for and can I set it from the layout xml properties like I can set OnClick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you have to set `addTextChangedListener()` to `editText`. Just as below:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(this);// your activity has to implement TextWatcher interface
```

Then you have to override this method:

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

You can use any of this method as you need and change your relevant views text.